# calculate days between two dates with condition

Tags: date, powerbi, powerquery

From the below table I want to calculate Days between Position filled and Availability Date where status is Open, so basically for how many days it was in Open until filled. For e.g. POS1 was filled on 17/08/2023 so Availability Date  - Filled Date is 77 days. I do not want to show days for filled as its filled.

| PositionID | Status | Availability Date | Position Filled | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| POS1 | Filled | 01/06/2023 | 17/08/2023 |  |
| POS1 | Filled | 01/06/2023 | 17/08/2023 |  |
| POS1 | Filled | 01/06/2023 | 17/08/2023 |  |
| POS1 | Filled | 01/06/2023 | 17/08/2023 |  |
| POS1 | Open | 01/06/2023 |  | 77 |
| POS1 | Open | 01/06/2023 |  | 77 |
| POS1 | Open | 01/06/2023 |  | 77 |
| POS1 | Open | 01/06/2023 |  | 77 |
| POS1 | Filled | 01/06/2023 | 17/08/2023 |  |
| POS1 | Open | 01/06/2023 |  | 77 |
| POS1 | Open | 01/06/2023 |  | 77 |
| POS1 | Filled | 01/06/2023 | 17/08/2023 |  |
| POS2 | Open | 15/10/2023 |  |  |
| POS3 | Open | 01/01/2023 |  | 90 |
| POS3 | Filled | 01/01/2023 | 01/04/2023 |  |

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark for answer to mark question as solved

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to find the non-null value for all matching PositionID Filled Dates, then subtract that from Position Date on the Open Rows

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{ {"Availability Date", type date}, {"Position Filled", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Temp",(x)=>try List.RemoveNulls(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each x[PositionID]=[PositionID])[Position Filled]){0} otherwise null),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Days", each if [Status] = "Open" then Duration.TotalDays([Temp]-[Availability Date]) else null, type number),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Temp"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]